# React async event handler. The safe way

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-functional-component

Imagine a simple react component

```js
const Upload: React.FC = () => {
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
    const upload = async () => {
        await doSomeAsyncStuffHere()
        setDone(true)
    }

    if(done) {
        return <div>success</div>
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={upload}>upload</button>
    )
}
```

It looks fine at first glance. But what if upload function takes a long time to finish? What if user navigates to another view and the component gets unmounted? When the async task finishes will cause a state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op and a possible memory leak. What should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Run it in a useEffect hook with a cleanup function (you shouldn't be causing side effects in a pure function component anyways). This is covered in [the hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks).

Comment: But I need to run it on user click event, not on render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of going about it is to create a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) that you set to `false` when the component is unmounted, and check against this before setting the result of your asynchronous code in the component state.

**Example**

```js
const Upload: React.FC = () => {
    const isMounted = useRef(true);
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
    const upload = async () => {
        await doSomeAsyncStuffHere()
        
        if (isMounted.current) {
            setDone(true)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            isMounted.current = false;
        };
    }, []);

    if(done) {
        return <div>success</div>
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={upload}>upload</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Fortunately it's no longer necessary to set `isMounted` refs on components. See this comment from Dan Abramov: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114